# Neyman-Pearson hypothesis testing with uniform random variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

This question is quite simple. We have a random sample $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ from $U(\theta, \theta + 1)$ and we want to test $H_0: \theta=0$ vs $H_0: \theta=\theta_1$ for some $0 < \theta_1 < 1$. We want to use *Neyman-Pearson's lemma* to find the most powerful test. The likelihood-ratio is

$\lambda = \frac{L_0}{L_1} = \frac{L(\theta_0 , x_1,x_2,...,x_n)}{L(\theta_1 , x_1,x_2,...,x_n)} = \frac{I_{(0, \infty)}(y_1)I_{(-\infty,1)}(y_n)}{I_{(\theta_1, \infty)}(y_1)I_{(-\infty,\theta_1 + 1)}(y_n)}$, where $y_1 = min(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y_n = max(x_1,...,x_n)$.

According to Neyman-Pearson, the most powerful test is $\Lambda \leqslant k$ for some $k$. If we want the test to have size $\alpha$ then we have to find $k$ such that $P_{\theta = 0}(\Lambda \leqslant k) = \alpha$.

If $\theta = 0$, $\Lambda$ equals just $\frac{1}{I_{(\theta_1, \infty)}(y_1)}$ so now we have to find $k$ such that $P_{\theta = 0}(\frac{1}{I_{(\theta_1, \infty)}(y_1)} \leqslant k) = \alpha$.

I don't know how to find such a $k$ and feel like I may be misunderstanding something.

Comment: You will need to explore the possibility of data for which the likelihood under one hypothesis is $1$ and under the other hypothesis is $0.$  In these cases your expression for $\Lambda$ is undefined, so you had better not rely on it.

Comment: So Neyman-Pearson's lemma is inapplicable in this situation?

Comment: It has to be carefully interpreted in this situation.  Consider rewriting the event $\Lambda \le k$ as $L_0 \le kL_1.$

Comment: Hi: This is not my field but ( my memory tells me ) that the uniform doesn't satisfy the regularity conditions for a standard Neyman Pearson approach. You have to use more intuition and I'm not even sure if the "heuristic" test is UMP. Hint: Think about what happens if you took a sample and the maximum value of the observations in such a sample was 1.9999. what would that tell you about $\theta$.

Comment: @mlofton I am testing $\theta = 0$ vs $\theta = \theta_1$ for some $0 < \theta_1 < 1$, so if any of the observations is more than 1, then I should reject the null hypothesis. A test could be: reject the null hypothesis if $max(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) > 1$, but how do I prove that it's the most powerful?

Comment: @whuber I feel like trying to use Neyman-Pearson's lemma and $\Lambda$ might not be the right way? Even if I write $\Lambda \leqslant k $ as $L_0 \leqslant kL_1$, it doesn't seem to be the right way because the value $k$ doesn't really affect the probability (under the null hypothesis) of the event $L_0 \leqslant kL_1$, does it? So I can't control the size of the test by varying $k$.

Comment: I don't think the theorem asserts you can create a test of *exactly* the intended size--but you definitely can control it.

Comment: Just a note: You are asked to find **a** most powerful test, not **the** most powerful test. MP tests are generally not unique.

Comment: whuber and stubborn atom. Thanks for setting me straight on UMP versus Most UMP. Noppaswee, Stubborn Atom gave a beautiful detailed presentation and I was just trying to give you a way to think about it. So, don't worry about my feeble attempt. Now that there is a beautiful explanation,  it's not worth thinking about..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likelihood ratio requires a bit more careful study here.

Pdf of the sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is $$f_{\theta}(\mathbf x)=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbf1_{\theta<x_i<\theta+1}=\mathbf1_{\theta<x_{(1)},x_{(n)}<\theta+1}\quad,\,\theta\in\mathbb R$$

I would define the ratio as $\Lambda=f_{H_1}/f_{H_0}$, for which I get the following cases:

\begin{align}
\Lambda(\mathbf x)=\frac{f_{H_1}(\mathbf x)}{f_{H_0}(\mathbf x)}&=\frac{\mathbf1_{\theta_1<x_{(1)},x_{(n)}<\theta_1+1}}{\mathbf1_{0<x_{(1)},x_{(n)}<1}}
\\\\&=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }\theta_1<x_{(1)},x_{(n)}<1 \\ \infty &,\text{ if }x_{(1)}>\theta_1,1<x_{(n)}<\theta_1+1 \\ 0&,\text{ if }0<x_{(1)}<\theta_1,x_{(n)}<1\end{cases}
\end{align}

By N-P lemma, you are to reject $H_0$ for large values of $\Lambda$. Can you give it a try now?

---

I found a similar exercise [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1HQmBKMgDaMC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA456#v=onepage&q&f=false) that asks to prove that a UMP test for testing $H_0:\theta\le 0$ vs $H_1:\theta>0$ is of the form

$$\varphi(\mathbf x)=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }x_{(1)}\ge k\,\,\text{ or }\,\,x_{(n)}\ge 1 \\ 0&,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

, where $k$ can be easily found so that size of $\varphi$ is $\alpha$.

This is exercise 6.6.18 of *Mathematical Statistics* by Shao (page 456, 2nd edition).

If you can see this page, then maybe you can use this exercise to verify your final results.

Comment: Thank you, you are wonderful. I am still digesting your answer.

Comment: You should verify the expression for $\Lambda$ first of all and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: I think I am supposed to use a randomised test, right? If $\theta_1 < x_{(1)}$ then I reject $H_0$ with some probability that makes the size of the test $ \alpha $.

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan No need for randomisation here.

Comment: No randomisation? I thought I understood but now I am back to being confused. The test I got is
---- reject $H_0$ if $X_{(n)} > 1$ (in this case $Y_{(1)} > \theta_1$)
---- accept $H_0$ if $X_{(n)} < 1$ and $X_{(1)} < \theta_1$
---- if $X_{(n)} < 1$ and $X_{(1)} > \theta_1$ then reject $H_0$ with probability $\frac{\alpha}{(1-\theta_0)^n}$
This test has size $\alpha$ and I think (but is not sure) is most powerful. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan Taking the critical region corresponding to the case $\Lambda=\infty$ is sufficient here. I don't understand the test you specified. Not that this test is unique, but $\varphi$ in my answer is an MP test for your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93425/discussion-between-noppawee-apichonpongpan-and-stubbornatom).